# A clean and intuitive way to implement a list of clickable strings to invoke functions?

Tags: qt, opengl, user-interface, event-handling

For the Qt App I'm writing, I'd like to have a list of clickable functions, which, when clicked will allow the user to supply required input arguments.

What I'm specifically looking for is a selection of widgets which provide a clean and intuitive interface for the following tasks:

- User scrolls through a list of functions for performing computations (in my case, from `glm`).
- Once a function is found, the user clicks on the item; a popup window opens, which specifies the required input arguments (e.g., `vec3`, `vec4`, etc.).

The idea here is that the functions themselves already exist: they just need an interface, which in a nutshell, provides a pseudo interpreter to process and output their results to a GLWidget, which will update the data passed accordingly by sending it to its corresponding shader.

I've looked at [QListView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html), and its Widget variant, but it appears to be more suited towards filesystem data, such as images or text files, though I'm not quite sure. So far, it seems to be the only thing which could be considered as realistically usable in this scenario.

Is there a recommended way to do this? I'm fairly new to Qt in general, thus my knowledge is pretty limited.

Answer (score 1):

The view isn't really important in your case. You need to create/reuse a adapted model.
This model have to contain the relation between what your view displays and the action that you want to launch.

For example, if your commands are text like bash commands, you can create a view that displays "list files", "Copy files" and a model that contains the data ("list files" = 'ls -l'), ("copy files" = 'ls -l'), etc.

You can store different data (using QVariant) in a same item with different roles: Qt::DisplayRole corresponds to the data that the view displays and Qt::UserRole what you want.

So, if you only have to store a command line associated to a name, you can store the name in the item with the Qt::DisplayRole and the command line as a QString (or other) using Qt::UserRole.

See QAbstractItemModel::data() and QAbstractItemModel::setData(), for more information.